# Where to find what commands/properties are available for AppleScript in Microsoft Outlook 2011

Tags: applescript

Does anyone know where I can find a list of available applescript commands/properties for Microsoft Outlook 2011?

I am trying to copy subject of the opened message into the clipboard and save the message as PDF to my desktop with subject as the file name.

Thanks.

Comment: The AppleScript dictionary isn't viable for some reason?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

All applications that are apple-scriptable have a "dictionary" of terms as part of the application itself. To access a dictionary open AppleScript Editor, under the File menu choose "open dictionary", and then choose the application.

A second way would be to drag/drop the application onto the AppleScript Editor icon in the dock or applications folder.

A third way... under the Window menu in AppleScript Editor choose "Library". That window is a quick-access tool to access the dictionaries of various applications. You can click the "+" button to add applications not in that list. Double-click an application in the list to access its dictionary.

A 4th way... if AppleScript Editor and the application you are interested in are both in the dock, you can command-drag the application's dock icon onto the AppleScript Editor's dock icon.

Comment: You seem to have misread my comment. As far as I know, the Outlook scripting dictionary is like any other. I wanted to know whether (and why) the OP found the dictionary unsuitable; it seemed unlikely to me that someone would be able to write any AppleScript without knowing about accessing the dictionary in AppleScript Editor. Basically, I didn't feel like writing an answer like yours without making sure that there was some point to it.

Comment: Got it Michael... I run across people all the time that do not know about accessing a dictionary so it's not all that uncommon. FYI: I edited my post removing the part about misunderstanding your comment.