# how CISCO able to integrate webex plugin for outlook mac

Tags: macos, plugins, outlook, outlook-addin, webex

I am developing a plug-in for outlook mac, I have search all over Google and community and everyone told me that its not possible to make Add-in for Outlook mac because it's simply doesn't support and I admitted but I have just seen the WebEx plugin for outlook and I am wondering how they are manage to do so? If anyone have idea I would really appreciate it

[image]

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: same question, any news on this?

Comment: Hey all, I also have a requirement to build this, can anyone please share their experience on same?

Answer (score 4):

You could use Applescript, which is supported in Outlook 2011 for Mac: http://www.officeformachelp.com/outlook/using-applescripts/

You can find other examples here: http://www.scriptsformac.com/script-download-index/outlook-for-mac-scripts/

Similarly, you will need to find the corresponding API points for adding menu items. One way would be to understand how the API(the objects and functions) available in VBA map to Applescript. Then see how the menu/toolbar items are added and do the corresponding stuff in applescript.

Also, see this [Where to find what commands/properties are available for AppleScript in Microsoft Outlook 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570855/where-to-find-what-commands-properties-are-available-for-applescript-in-microsof)

Comment: VBA to applescript mapping is not available with Outlook 2011 as I found :(

Comment: You don't need 'VBA to Applescript' mapping. What you need is the Outlook API exposed to Applescript, which you can find via the link in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570855/where-to-find-what-commands-properties-are-available-for-applescript-in-microsof

Comment: how to add that kind of additional button to outlook . can we do it through the appleScript ?

Answer (score -1):

They reverse engineered Outlook and put their icon in the menu.  There is no APIs that Microsoft exposes like on Windows Outlook.

Comment: that's simply not true. Microsoft has tools for customising office apps. I am aware of VSTO but i suspect there are others too.

Comment: @Stewart_R VSTO is not related to mac